# Magento 2: Delete duplicate products programatically

Tags: magento2, database, collection, delete

I need to search **Magento 2** DB for **duplicate SKUs** and remove duplicate products using a script, i found a very useful script here: 
[Remove duplicated products from catalog](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/remove-duplicated-products-from-catalog).
but it's not compatible with **Magento 2** as Mag 2 is not using Mage class or `Mage.php`
can someone please convert following code to a Magento 2 version:

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

$limit    = 100;
$model    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$resource = $model->getResource();
$adapter  = $resource->getReadConnection();
$name     = $resource->getAttribute('sku');

// retrieve a list of all products that have more than 1 occurrence of the same name
$select = $adapter->select()->from(
    $name->getBackendTable(),
    array(
        $resource->getIdFieldName(),
        'value',
        'count'      => 'COUNT(*)',
        'entity_ids' => new Zend_Db_Expr("GROUP_CONCAT({$resource->getIdFieldName()})")
    )
);
$select->where('attribute_id = ?', $name->getAttributeId());
$select->where('entity_type_id = ?', $name->getEntityTypeId());
$select->group('value');
$select->having('count > 1');
$select->limit($limit);
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($select);

// here, we remove the lowest product id from each set of duplicate-named products. 
// the theory is that the product which was created first, hence the lowest 
// product id, is the one you want to keep
$result = array_map(
    function ($row) {
        $entityIds = explode(',', $row['entity_ids']);
        $min       = min($entityIds);
        $key       = array_search($min, $entityIds);
        unset($entityIds[$key]);
        $row['entity_ids'] = $entityIds;

        return $row;
    },
    $result
);

// now that we have narrowed down to the ids of the products we want to delete, 
// lets get all product ids to delete into a single array
$entityIds = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $entityIds = array_merge($entityIds, $row['entity_ids']);
}

// lets delete each one individually
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter($resource->getIdFieldName(), array('in' => $entityIds));
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->delete();
}
?>
```